# PHP : page only updated in Firefox but not with Chrome nor Internet Explorer

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, caching, explorer

I have a small issue, probably of caching.
Here is my configuration :

- Lamp Server
- Last version of Ubuntu

I have a simple page wich, on click, modifies items ont the mySQL Database and then reload the page.

Here is the problem : both on server (Ubuntu) and the client (Windows 8.1) side, the page works properly only on Firefox. For example, on Chrome or IE, the page updates only the first time, and then seems to be static.
I even tried to put "hard" stuff on the code like ***exit;*** but it obviously doesn't do anything. This basic stuff only works with Firefox.

I thinks about a cache problem, but I don't know where to look.

EDIT: code

```
if(isset($_GET['Id']) && $this->isInt($_GET['Id'])){
        $leCommercial = $this->getManagerCommerciaux()->Find($_GET['Id']);
        if(!$leCommercial){
            return "No retailer found";
        }else{
            if($leCommercial->getActif() == 0){
                $leCommercial->setActif(1);
            }else{
                $leCommercial->setActif(0);
            }
            $this->getManagerCommerciaux()->Save($leCommercial);
            $this->redirect($this->Shortcuts->getUrlSite().'commerciaux/');
        }
    }else{
        return "Id is missing or a the bad format!";
    }
```

Comment: Really? You're not going to show us any code, and we're just supposed to guess at what's causing the problem? You've been around SO long enough to know better.

Comment: no code = no problem ... unless we are some kind of magicians or something and we will guess what's causing your issue... in this case, just wait until someone guesses and you will be good to go :)

Comment: As it works perfectly on FF, I supposed it is a configuration problem...Sorry, my bad, I'll put the code

Comment: Definitely a cache problem. Still looking where it comes from. As it is the first time I use PHP 5.5...

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

In my PHP code, I made a redirection with the 301 header.
Google chrome cache this kind of redirection for a quite lonnnng time.